# Cors in capacitor for android

Tags: android, angular, spring, nginx, capacitor

I want to convert my `angular` web app to mobile app.
I understand how works cors in web, there is just need to set port in frontend and the same port and url in backend `allowedOrigins` settings.  But I can't understand how does work cors in mobile app because IP is different in each mobile device, not static like in frontend.

I can config in my computer something like this:

In server:

```
app:
  auth:
  cors:
    allowedOrigins: http://127.0.0.1:8100,
```

In mobile app (capacitor.config.ts):

```
import { CapacitorConfig } from '@capacitor/cli';

const config: CapacitorConfig = {
  appId: 'com.my.app',
  appName: 'my-mobile',
  webDir: 'dist/my-mobile',
  bundledWebRuntime: false,
  server: {
    cleartext: true,
    hostname: '127.0.0.1:8100',
  }
};

export default config;
```

And this works, but in locale, how to do it in prod, on real android devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got answer here https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-works-cors-in-capasitor-on-real-devices/230474

In prod, the apps run at the following URL/origin by default:

iOS: capacitor://localhost
Android: http://localhost
So, both of those need to be configured in your backend as allowed origins. You could also use Capacitor’s HTTP plugin to get around CORS all together.